# No consigo montar una expresión regular que me filtre un texto

Tags: php, regex

Tengo un texto en el que tengo a la vez texto normal y texto dentro de doble corchete, quiero recuperar el texto que tengo entre doble corchete para poder procesarlo y luego hacer un cambio en el texto normal.

> Esto es un
> wadus[[{json que va dentro de los corchetes}]] la verdad es que si pero puede
> ser también que no
> [[{json dos que va dentro de los corchetes}]] esto es otro texot de ejemplo
> de lo que viene a continuación

Estoy mirando con esta expresión regular que he sacado:
`/\[{2}+[^.]+\]{2}/m` esta mal porque en https://regexr.com/ me señala a la vez ambos json y el texto que esta entre ambos como resultado.

Comment: No se si esto te servirá https://regex101.com/r/7ULIGp/1

Comment: No me devuelve nada, lo estoy ejecutando en un php 8.0 :/

Comment: Pues a mi me funciona bien https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/7c671

Comment: Jaime, tienes toda la razón, he debido de copiar mal la expresión regular de regex101.com, ahora si funciona.
#Gracias.

Comment: De nada Oscar. La que pones en tu pregunta también es válida solo que le falta la bandera `U`.